# How can I access related_name from a model inside another app in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I am working with models from differents apps in **Django**.

I have two apps. One is called *partners* and other *contracts*.

In the app *partners*, inside the file **models.py**, I have this model defined:

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=False, blank=True)
```

In the app *contracts*, inside the file **models.py**, I have this model defined:

```
from partners.models import Partner

class Contract(models.Model):
    ...
    indications = models.ManyToManyField(Partner, through='ContractIndication', related_name='indications')

class ContractIndication(models.Model):
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payed = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=YES_NO, null=False, blank=True, default='N')
```

However, in the file **views.py** from *partners* app, I cannot access all the contracts that a partner is linked to, using this:

```
partner = Partner.objects.get(...)
indications = partner.indications.all()
```

I am already using the **related_name** attribute from Contract. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you created and run all your migrations? Does it work if you use `partner.contrato_set.all()`?

Comment: Yes, it works using your suggestion. But why does it not work using the related_name?